# Modulo for doubles

Tags: c, math

I need to work out if a massive integer (I mean 20 digits...) is prime.

I'm trying to use the brute-force method, but (of course) I need to use doubles to contain the original number. However, the modulo operator (%) is an integer operator - thus it is useless to me!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's not possible, a double only has 15 significant digits.  Look for an implementation of a [BigInt class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/how-to-implement-big-int-in-c)  C specific is discussed [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565150/bigint-in-c)

Comment: Interesting link on first glance, I'll make sure and read it! Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 3):

Since the double data type is stored as a fractional value scaled to some power of two, and since it only has a precision of 15 decimal digits, a 20-digit number stored as a double will always be divisible by two, and therefore, is not prime.

Comment: That explains one of the bugs I was getting - thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `fmod` in the C standard library? Or possibly `fmodl`for `long double`?

Comment: It's fmodl for long double. Thanks!