# Recursive fibonacci

Tags: c, fibonacci

I am trying to generate Fibonacci series and provided the code for the same below. When I run this code for smaller values, it outputs correct results. However, when I try and calculate series for a number say '50', it out puts correct results upto the 47th number and result for 48,49 and 50th term are incorrect. I tried using unsigned long int as well but it did not correct the results. Can some please suggest what am I doing wrong here. 
Thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
unsigned long long int fibr(unsigned long long int);

int main(){
    unsigned long long  int n;
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf("%llu",&n);
    //res=fibr(n);
      while(n>=0){
          printf("%llu\n",fibr(n));
          n--;
           }
     }
unsigned long long int fibr(unsigned long long int n){
     if((n==0)||(n==1))
         return n;
     else return fibr(n-1)+fibr(n-2);
     }
```

'After the suggestions , I incorporated unsigned long long int. Have modified the code above but now it gives a seg fault. Any hints please. I am not allowed to use any other library except the standards one available. '

Comment: You may be able to bump up the size of the integer type you're using a few times, but if you need to compute even larger numbers, you might have to start looking into some kind of arbitrary-precision library.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag with [tag:homework].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer to your second question:

I think you had this problem from the beginning:

```
while(n>=0){
```

is an infinite loop since `n` is an unsigned integer. `n` will go negative due to the decrement. But since it's unsigned, it will wrap around and cause a stack-overflow in your recursion.

Also, your algorithm is probably slowest way to do this. It runs in exponential time. So it will take a very long time to run it when `n` is big.

A better way is just this:

```
int n = 48;
return (unsigned long long)(pow(1.6180339887498948,n) * 0.44721359549995794 + 0.5);
```

This method will run in constant time. :)

Comment: Thanks Mystical for pointing this out. This did the job. Also it is slow but a requirement for assignment as now this needs to be divided into threads and timing needs to be calculated. I am sure would have not been able to figure out the n>=0 for unsigned it.. thanks again

Comment: Also, don't use my answer unless you can figure how/why it works. I'll leave the proof as an exercise. :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using `unsigned long long`?

Comment: @Faizan - This is because the complexity of recursive Fibonacci is `2^n`. You are computing the same values again and again. Either use memoization(saving results) or turn it to iterative version.

Comment: @Faizan - Also remove the `unsigned` from `unsigned long long  int n;` (the first line after main method)

Answer (score 0):

C data types are limited in size. So if you use `int`, `long` or `long long`, at some point, your result will overflow, due to the fast-growing nature of fibonacci-numbers.
To store such big numbers, you'll need some `BigInteger` implementation. Have a look at [“BigInt” in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565150/bigint-in-c) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You get integer overflow. For `unsigned int` the largest possible value is 4294967295, but 48th Fibonacci number is 4807526976.

Answer (score 0):

Converting `fibr()` to memoize its results reduces the running time for fibr(90) to a few milliseconds on my machine. Switching from recursion to iteration should have similar results.