# Representing a long number using c language

Tags: c

I am trying to represent a very long number (i.e between 13 to 16 numerical digits) using C . `long long` does not seem to work as I am always getting an overflow problem.

I would appreciate it if someone can help me with this problem, thank you.

```
long long number = 123654123654123LL;
printf("%ull", number);
```

Comment: You can use a library, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565150/bigint-in-c

Comment: You shouldn't attempt to print a long long as an unsigned long long.

Comment: `long long` is guaranteed to hold up to at least 2^63-1, which has 19 decimal digits (to those who saw my previous comment -- yep, I can't count). So once you fix your print statement you should be good to go.

Comment: Steve, thank you, the print statement was not correct due to a typo mistake, in the program it was written with small 'p' letter.

Answer (score 6):

The format specifier is incorrect it should be `%llu` and the type for `number` should be `unsigned long long`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long number = 123654123654123LL;
    printf("%llu\n", number);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 123654123654123

See http://ideone.com/i7pLX.

The format specifier `%ull` is actually `%u` followed by two `l` (ell) characters.

From the section *5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>* of the C99 standard the maximum values for `long long` and `unsigned long long` are guaranteed to be at least:

```
LLONG_MAX +9223372036854775807 // 263 − 1
ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615 // 264 − 1
```

so `123654123654123` is comfortably within range.

Comment: Thank you, it is a typo mistake, was not intentional. Thank you for noting it.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using dev c++,  I wrote the same code as suggested but still it overflow...

Comment: @Sinan, `#include <limits.h>` and print out the values of the _Limits of integer types_ macros listed on [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits). That will tell you what is supported. On my 32-bit XP machine the `ULLONG_MAX` has a value of `18446744073709551615`.

Comment: @Sinan 123654123654123 is too small to overflow any legitimate `long long` or `unsigned long long` type. What exactly happens when you compile and run hmjd's code?

Comment: @hmjd, thank you. I did that and the output was 4294967295 which is smaller than the required number I am trying to print. My code was printf("%llu", ULL_MAX); can you confirm if that is the correct way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks. When I wrote hmjd code and run it, the output was this number (201511380).