# Product of Products of elements of all subsequences of length k of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, combinatorics, subsequence

I have been given an array of length of **n**. I have to find the product of products of elements of all subsequences of length **k**.

For e.g

Array        ->     [1,2,3,4]     **n**=4,**k**=2

Subsequences ->     {1,2} {1,3} {1,4} {2,3} {2,4} {3,4}

Products     ->       2   3     4       6    8     12

Product of products 2*3*4*6*8*12 = 13824

It can be done easily if **n** & **k** are small but I am not able to get the result when  **1<=n<=2000**, **1<=k<=n**. The answer can be too large so we can give the answer modulo **1000000007**. Can someone tell me how to do it for large **n** & **k**?

Comment: Sounds like a great exercise. Did you have a *question* ?

Comment: Tip: `(a*b)%c = ((a%c) * (b%c))%c`

Comment: In your example: 13824 = 1 ** 3 * 2 ** 3 * 3 ** 3 * 4 ** 3 (** means to the power of)

Comment: @WhozCraig how can we do it efficiently for large n & k?

Comment: @user202729 Welcome to the question. it's change since I posted the first comment. The closing sentence added, it has merit (and plenty of duplicates, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235008/how-to-find-muliplication-of-large-numbers-modulo-100000007) ).

Comment: @WhozCraig the link tells how to multiply two big numbers modulo a prime..but how to multiply   2*2*2*......2 , 123456789561234563141515 times modulo a prime which can not be stored in any data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More hints:

Fermat's little theorem states (with `^` denotes explanation)

`n^(p-1) ≡ 1     (mod p)` for all prime `p` and `n` coprime with `p`.

Therefore, `n^x ≡ n^(x mod (p-1))     (mod p)`

Now use Pascal's triangle or anything that may help computing `x mod (p-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Product of products means the same as product: (a_1 * a_2) * (a_3 * a_4) = a_1 * a_2 * a_3 * a_4.

Product of products of subsequences can be efficiently calculated with power: (a_1  * a_2) * (a_1 * a_3) * (a_2 * a_3) = a_1 * a_1 * a_2 * a_2 * a_3 * a_3 = a_1 ** 2 * a_2 ** 2 * a_3 ** 2

Find `n` the number of subsequences, containing the first element. Then calculate each element (`a_i ** n = a'_i`) to the power of `n`. Then calculate the product of all `a'_i`.

Also for (a * a * a) % b = ((((a* a) % b) * a) % b)

and

(a *b )%c = ((a%c) * (b%c))%c

Comment: I tried to do it that way,the power will be (n-1)C(k-1) (combinations).But when n & k    are too large, the power will be too large to handle.

Comment: As Yksisarvinen said: (a*b)%c = ((a%c) * (b%c))%c

Comment: OK! Let's say n=2000 & k=1000 so number of subsequences containing the first element will be (1999)C(999) (fixing the  first element and selecting other k-1 elements). Now this power can not be stored in any standard data type. Now?

Comment: You have to calculate the power by yourself: (2000 * 2000 * 2000 * 2000) % 1000000007 = ((8000000000 % 1000000007) * 2000) % 1000000007 = (999999951 * 2000) % 1000000007 = 999888007

Comment: I know the use of modulus. I have to multiply 2000, (1999)C(999) times but how do I get (1999)C(999) (nCr)as it is too large.