# C++: What exactly happens when I'm multiplying longlongint and int? (Fibonacci with matrix multiplication problem)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm solving a coding problem with Fibonacci numbers, and I have a code for matrix multiplication here.

The problem is getting a n < 10^18, and printing F_n % MOD.
(MOD = 1,000,000,007). I did it by matrix multiplication.
F_1000 % MOD is supposed to be 517691607,but my code ends up printing 589888339.

```
#define MOD 1000000007

//C=A*B
void matrix_mul(vector<vector<long long int>> A, vector<vector<long long int>> B, vector<vector<long long int>> &C, int n, int m, int k)
{
    long long int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < m; x++)
            {
                sum += (long long)(A[i][x]* B[x][j]) % (long long)MOD;
                sum %= MOD;
            }
            C[i][j] = sum;
        }
}
```

The code runs properly until 45, where F_45 < MOD and F_46 > MOD, but F_1000 is wrong. So I think the problem should be something with the `sum += (long long)(A[i][x]* B[x][j]) % (long long)MOD;` line, but I don't get what I'm wrong. Is there something wrong that I'm missing?
Here's the whole code if you need it.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#define MOD 1000000007

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <queue>
#include <complex>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;


//C=A*B
void matrix_mul(vector<vector<long long int>> A, vector<vector<long long int>> B, vector<vector<long long int>> &C, int n, int m, int k)
{
    long long int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < m; x++)
            {
                sum += (long long)(A[i][x]* B[x][j]) % (long long)MOD;
                sum %= MOD;
            }
            C[i][j] = sum;
        }
}

void print_matrix(vector<vector<long long int>>A)
{
    int a = A.size();
    int b = A[0].size();
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            printf("%lld ", A[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{ 
    long long int n;
    scanf("%lld", &n);
    vector<vector<long long int>> A;
    vector<vector<vector<long long int>>> A_2;
    A.push_back({1,1});
    A.push_back({1,0});
    A_2.push_back(A);
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) A_2.push_back({{0,0},{0,0}});
    //A의 2^i
    for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++) matrix_mul(A_2[i], A_2[i], A_2[i+1], 2,2,2);

    //A^b: 1. [1,1,1,0]^n-2
    vector<vector<long long int>> I = {{1,0},{0,1}};
    int k = 0;
    if (n == 1) printf("%d", 0);
    else
    {
        n-=2; //n-2승을 구할 거므로
        while(n!=0)
        {
            if(n%2)
                matrix_mul(I, A_2[k], I, 2,2,2);
            n/=2;
            k++;
        }
        printf("%lld\n", I[0][0]);
    }

    //long long int f_44 = 433494437, f_45 = 701408733;
    //printf("%lld %lld %lld", f_44, f_45, (f_44 + f_45) % 1000000007);

    return 0;
}
```

The fibonnachi numbers are
f_44 = 433494437, f_45 = 701408733, f_46 = 1134903170,(f_44, f_45 < MOD, f_46 > MOD) and until f_46 it's all right.

Comment: `(a * b) mod m` can also be calculated as `((a mod m) * (b mod m)) mod m`.  This relationship can be used to remove any potential overflow from the `a * b` part.

Comment: If you really want to have control over the size of your integers use std::int64_t or use a large int library.

Comment: `long long int` and the number `1e9` tell me this is a competitive programming problem, those usually need  a mathematical insight or trick to meet the expected time and memory constraints.

Comment: Why do you need matrix multiplication for calculating Fibonacci numbers? (a+b) mod M is just (a mod M + b mod M) - you shouldn't get overflow anywhere.

Comment: @lastchance n=10^18, and it doesn't finish in time if you do a+b. So I used divide & conquer with matrix multiplication

Comment: Is it a typo? Your comment says `//A^b: 1. [1,1,1,0]^n-2` but you initialize the vector with `I = {{1,0},{0,1}};`. If I change that to `I = {{1,1},{1,0}};`, then I get your "expected" value for F_1000.

Comment: `#include`ing most of the standard library and `using namespace std` is a great way to [shoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) yourself in the foot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to find muliplication of large numbers modulo 100000007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235008/how-to-find-muliplication-of-large-numbers-modulo-100000007)

Comment: @이형주 , if you simply enter n=1001 you will get f_1000 mod M. You are out by 1 in n (mainly because of the way that you have initiated the matrix power calculation).

Answer (score 0):

You will notice that having both `n-=2` and `printf("%lld\n", I[0][0])` is not correct if you lay out your dp formula.

```
[dp[m]]      =  [1 1]^(m - 2) * [dp[2]]
[dp[m - 1]]     [1 0]           [dp[1]]
```

So you should be printing `(I[0][0] + I[0][1]) % MOD`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not convinced that your model fibonacci numbers for f_44, f_45 and f_46 are correct: you seem to be "out by 1" in n (or, at least, using a different numbering convention); this would lead you to get a different value for f_1000. (You might like to try f_999 and f_1001 with your code).

If you want a fast matrix exponent with the correct n then you have to start with the identity matrix. (Here, "correct" means "that which will give you your intended value of f_1000 mod M").

Try this (coded from the matrix form in reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

using INT = unsigned long long;
using MATRIX = vector<vector<INT>>;
const INT M = 1'000'000'007;


MATRIX mat2mul( const MATRIX &A, const MATRIX &B )    // multiply 2 x 2 matrices, mod M.
{
   return { { ( A[0][0] * B[0][0] + A[0][1] * B[1][0] ) % M, ( A[0][0] * B[0][1] + A[0][1] * B[1][1] ) % M },
            { ( A[1][0] * B[0][0] + A[1][1] * B[1][0] ) % M, ( A[1][0] * B[0][1] + A[1][1] * B[1][1] ) % M } };
}


MATRIX power( MATRIX A, INT exponent )                // integer power of 2 x 2 matrix, mod M
{
   MATRIX result = { { 1ull, 0ull }, { 0ull, 1ull } };
   for ( ; exponent; A = mat2mul( A, A ), exponent /= 2 ) if ( exponent % 2 ) result = mat2mul( result, A );
   return result;
}


int main()
{
   MATRIX A = { { 1ull, 1ull }, { 1ull, 0ull } };
   INT n;
   cout << "Input n: ";   cin >> n;
   A = power( A, n );
   cout << A[0][1] << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Input n: 1000
517691607
```