# Algorithm returns garbage when input is too large?

Tags: c, algorithm, primes

I started working on Project Euler problems today to keep myself busy over break. One of the problems asks for the sum of all prime numbers below 2 million, so I threw together a Sieve of Eratosthenes to find all those numbers.

```
unsigned long i, j, sum = 0, limit = 2000000;

// Allocate an array to store the state of numbers (1 is prime, 0 is not).
int* primes = malloc(limit * sizeof(int));

// Initialize every number as prime.
for (i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    primes[i] = 1;

// Use the sieve to check off values that are not prime.
for (i = 2; i*i < limit; i++)
    if (primes[i] != 0)
        for (j = 2; i*j < limit; j++)
            primes[i*j] = 0;

// Get the sum of all numbers still marked prime.
for (i = 2; i < limit; i++)
    if (primes[i] != 0)
        sum += i;

printf("%d", sum);
```

This works perfectly up to `limit` around half a million. After this, it returns random values (for example, 1000000 returns -1104303641). I've tried declaring all the `unsigned long` variables as `unsigned long long` to no avail. The error seems to be happening in the last 4 lines, because `primes[]` contains nothing but 1's and 0's at that point. I figure this has something to do with the size of the values being worked with, can anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: @totymedli: Are you really suggesting that the OP should allocate an array of two million longs on the stack??

Comment: what size is long on your platform?  printf("%d\n", sizeof(long));

Comment: have you tried a different format string? %l instead of %d? or maybe %ul for unsigned long?

Comment: I just ran this and it looks good on my mac.  Change the printf at the end of ld and I get: 142913828922 -- which is inline with what daniel fischer said

Comment: The sum of the primes `<= N` is roughly `N²/(2*log N)`. So for `N = 2000000`, that's a bit more than 10^11 and doesn't fit in a 32-bit integer.

Comment: @xaxxon Your mac is 64-bits.

Comment: That's your problem then.  You're on a 32-bit platform.  You're going to need some sort of third-party long-int.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the %d to %ld and you should get:

142913828922

which seems like it should be (close to or) the right answer.

..assuming your longs aren't 32-bit.

If you're on a 32-bit platform, you're going to need some sort of third-party big int library.

[BigInteger in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565150/bigint-in-c)

recommends: http://gmplib.org/

Comment: Changing %d to %ld or %ul yields 1179908154, which is indeed closer to the right answer.

Answer (score 6):

Wolfram Alpha tells me that the sum of the primes less than 500000 is [9914236195](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+primes+less+than+500000).

That number doesn't fit in a 32 bit integer, so you're overflowing an int during your sum loop. You could try to use a `uint64_t`, but that problem will eventually occur again with a high enough limit (although I suspect that a limit of 2000000 will fit).

Comment: What `int`, the index of the array? How do I change that to `uint64_t`?

Comment: no, there is no need to change the index of the array.  Only the sum, but that's already a long

Comment: Looks like you can't run that query for 2000000 unless you have a pro account.  Standard computation time exceeded...