# Casting a double or float to an integer type, which type?

Tags: c, types, casting

If I wanted to cast a float or double to an integer type, and I didnt want it to overflow under any circumstances, how should I go about choosing an integer type?

Comment: That's just not possible. No integer type covers the full float/double range.

Comment: @undur_gongor at least no integer type is **guaranteed** to cover it. In C, integer types only have *minimal* widths, not maximal ones.

Comment: Check the value of the float and see if it fits. If it doesn't, blow up the universe to ensure "not under any circumstances".

Comment: If you want an integer type that will cover a larger range than the built-in types, you might be interested in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565150/bigint-in-c

Comment: @user3477950: You are right. There could be 129 bit integers that would cover the full IEEE754 single range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range for `floats` is almost always larger than the `long long` or `int64` (but it can depend on the implementation).

For example, in .Net the range of `float` is `3.4E +/- 38` , but the range for `long long` and `int64`  is –`9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. You just can't be sure that you will not overflow. Other implementations of C and C++ have similar ranges.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx.

Comment: "but the range for `long long` is such and such" -- **at least.** Nothing prevents an implementation from supplying a, say, 1024-bit wide `long long`.

Comment: This answer would make sense if the question was about Visual C++, but there is no sign in the question that this is what the OP uses.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to cast int to float and back. It is possible because of most modern computers share 32bit storage. What this allows is using a union. for example:

```
    union
    {
        float x;
        int i;
    } u;
```

Here you are free to assign a float `u.x=391` and then make use of the integer representation `int myint = u.i` There is nothing to prevent the use with other storage classes. However, you must check the most significant bit and insure `1 <= msb < 32` or you are guaranteed to fail. In the instance where a double has a msb < 32 it receive like treatment.

This is not recommended and is as best implementation defined behavior. The numeric storage of floats in ieee754 format define the 32bit storage. It in itself in an entire other discussion. You can test this method, look at the ieee754 storage format and understand the limitations they pose.

Comment: here you are not casting the `float` to an `int`, but you are reinterpreting its representation.