# Convert a big number given as a string to an OpenSSL BIGNUM

Tags: c, openssl, bignum

I am trying to convert a string `p_str` representing a big integer to a `BIGNUM` `p` using the OpenSSL library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main ()
{
  /* I shortened the integer */
  unsigned char *p_str = "82019154470699086128524248488673846867876336512717";

  BIGNUM *p = BN_bin2bn(p_str, sizeof(p_str), NULL);

  BN_print_fp(stdout, p);
  puts("");

  BN_free(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled it with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -o convert convert.c -lcrypto
```

But, when I execute it, I get the following result:

```
3832303139313534
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ```
> unsigned char *p_str = "82019154470699086128524248488673846867876336512717";
>
> BIGNUM *p = BN_bin2bn(p_str, sizeof(p_str), NULL);
> ```

Use `int BN_dec2bn(BIGNUM **a, const char *str)` instead.

You would use `BN_bin2bn` when you have an array of `bytes` (and not a NULL terminated ASCII string).

The man pages are located at [`BN_bin2bn(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BN_bn2bin.html).

The correct code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main ()
{
  static const
  char p_str[] = "82019154470699086128524248488673846867876336512717";

  BIGNUM *p = BN_new();
  BN_dec2bn(&p, p_str);

  char * number_str = BN_bn2hex(p);
  printf("%s\n", number_str);

  OPENSSL_free(number_str);
  BN_free(p);

  return 0;
}
```