# Why the factorial of 153 has failed in following program

Tags: c, pointers, header, long-integer, factorial

I have created a myfun.h header file with two functions in it. A factorial function and amstrong function and a myfun.c file
Here is myfun.h program

```
void factorial(int n,int *fact)
{
    int i;
    *fact=1;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      *fact=*fact*i;
}
amstrong(int n)
{
    int sum=0,num,rem,cube;         
    num=n;
    while(num>0)
    { 
      rem=num%10;
      cube=rem*rem*rem;        
      num=num/10;
      sum=sum+cube;
    }
    if(sum==n)                         
      return(1);  
    else
      return(0);
 }
```

Here is the myfun.c program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "myfun.h"
int main()
{
    int num,rev,f,code;
    printf("Enter number :");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    code=amstrong(num);
    if(code==1)
      printf("\nNumber is amstrong\n");  
    else
      printf("Number is not amstrong\n");
    factorial(num,&f);
    printf("Factorial of %d is %d ",num,f);
    getch();
}
```

In this the amstrong function is working fine.But the factorial function is giving output 0. I haven't tried it without removing pointer variable. But if i want to run it with pointer variable then what changes i need to do?

The output of program is

```
Enter number: 153
Number is amstrong
Factorial of 153 is 0
```

Comment: i think `fact(153)` will be bigger then what `int` can hold.

Comment: You are right! When i give smaller value it gives correct output.

Comment: what should be done to get output of value 153

Comment: use long double instead of int

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`153! = 2.01 E+269`.

In case `unsigned long long` is 64 bits, it can hold a maximum value of `2^64 = 18.45 E+19`.

You will need to use some form of ["big int" library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565150/bigint-in-c) to calculate huge numbers like these.

Comment: the fact parameter is only an int, so this answer is meaningless in the context of the question

Comment: @user3629249 It is assumed that the reader understands that unsigned long long is the largest standard integer type available, yet I showed it is too small. Sizes of integers is usually addressed in chapter 1 of your average C beginner's book.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because there is a every data type can hold upto a certain number. The reason that you are getting wrong answer is because the `fact` of `153` would be bigger then what an `int` variable can hold. It should work fine for smaller values.

**Edit**

To store larger numbers you can use `long long int` data type.

Comment: i didn't say it will work for `fact(153)`. *I said to store larger numbers*.

Comment: but his problem is with factorial of 153

Comment: i have tried using long unsigned int , but still its showing 0 output

Comment: actually the largest factorial that can be stored in an int variable is only 12.  13 exceeds the size of a int variable (31bits+sign)  13 factorial is 6,227,020,800 (greater than 6gig) and 12 factorial is 479,001,600 (less than .5gig)  and the max value in an int is 2gig

Answer (score 1):

The minimum data type ranges you can use are:

```
short int and int: -32,767 to 32,767
unsigned short int and unsigned int: 0 to 65,535
long int: -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647
unsigned long int: 0 to 4,294,967,295
```

int alone cannot store the value given by fact (153). Use smaller values for your case, otherwise change the type: use a long long int instead.

Comment: Maybe try a long long int = 8 bytes or long double = 12 bytes .

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(long double) = 12`bytes on a machine running 32-bit linux. The output can be printed by using `%LE` in `printf`. Output will be in exponential form.

**EDIT**

factorial(20) : 2432902008176640000 when using `long long int`
This is maximum you can get with `long long int` type of variable.
For greater ranges use `long double`.