# Is it possible to create an integer of any size with dynamic memory?

Tags: c, bigint

Is it possible to use dynamic memory allocation, or some other method, to make a 1000-bit (or 1024-bit) integer variable?

Obviously, this is an insane amount, but I'm just using this amount as an example. Basically, can I make an integer any size I want? I'm thinking maybe dynamic memory allocation would work, or perhaps something to do with char arrays?

Comment: No. The CPU can only do arithmetic on its native integer sizes.

Comment: You can allocate any amount of memory and call it an "integer" but you have to do the manipulation and arithmetic yourself.

Comment: Not quite any size, just as much as the system will give you. That may be larger than physical memory; the operating system can use swap space to provide additional memory, but there is some limit.

Comment: ...I just learned a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what exactly you mean.
If you mean "a fully functional `int` that the compiler knows how to handle and can be used with the built-in arithmetic operators", the answer would be no.
If you mean "allocate an arbitrary size of memory that I'll treat as a continuous integer and write my own custom mathematical functions for", the answer is most definitely yes, and there are in fact [several libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/565150/2422776) that do exactly that.

Comment: Perfect! My reasoning for this is a mix of curiosity and practical applications (i.e. writing a code to find giant prime numbers). I'm mostly curious as to how computer are able to store and process numbers with millions of digits.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For example the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library) (GMP) does this.