# Addition of 2 numbers in C the simple human way

Tags: c

Just for fun, I'm trying to write a code in C which adds 2 numbers the way human do. **However the code breaks if they are of same length.**  There are other ways to add 2 really big numbers however they add using tricks like reversing the number, bit operator or using long; which is not what I'm looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *ptr, *ptr2, *ptr3;
    int size, size2, size3, carry = 0;
    
    printf("Enter size of 1st element: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    ptr = (int *)calloc(size, sizeof(int));
    if (ptr == NULL)
        printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
    else {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            scanf("%d", &ptr[j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nEnter size of 2nd element: ");
    scanf("%d", &size2);
    ptr2 = (int *)calloc(size2, sizeof(int));
    if (ptr2 == NULL)
        printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
    else {
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; ++j) {
            scanf("%d", &ptr2[j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Addition starts here

    if (size > size2)
        size3 = size + 1;
    else
        size3 = size2 + 1;
    ptr3 = (int *)calloc(size3, sizeof(int));
    for (int j = 0; j < size3; ++j) {
        ptr3[j]=0;
    }

    if (size > size2) {     //1st number higher digits
        for (int k = 1; k <= size2; ++k) {
            ptr3[k - 1] = (carry + ptr[size - k] + ptr2[size2 - k]);
            carry = ptr3[k - 1] / 10;
            ptr3[k - 1] = ptr3[k - 1] % 10;
        }
        for (int k = size2 + 1; k <= size; ++k) {
            if (k == size2)
                ptr3[k - 1] = ptr[size - k] + carry;
            else
                ptr3[k - 1] = ptr[size - k];
        }
    } else if (size2 > size)  { //2nd number higher digits
        for (int k = 1; k <= size; ++k) {
            ptr3[k - 1] = (carry + ptr2[size2 - k] + ptr[size - k]);
            carry = ptr3[k - 1] / 10;
            ptr3[k - 1] = ptr3[k - 1] % 10;
        }
        for (int k = size + 1; k <= size2; ++k) {
            if (k == size)
                ptr3[k - 1] = ptr2[size2 - k] + carry;
            else
                ptr3[k - 1] = ptr2[size2 - k];
        }       
    } else {                //equal digits
        for (int k = size; k > -1; --k) {
            ptr3[k] = (carry + ptr2[k] + ptr[k]);
            printf("%d + %d = %d\n", ptr2[k], ptr[k], ptr3[k]);
            carry = ptr3[k] / 10;
            ptr3[k] = ptr3[k] % 10;
        }
    }

    //  DISPLAY     
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        printf("%d", ptr[j]);
    }
    printf("+");
    for (int j = 0; j < size2; ++j) {
        printf("%d", ptr2[j]);
    }
    printf(" = ");
    for (int j = size3; j > -1; --j) {
        if (ptr3[j] >= 0)
            printf("%d", ptr3[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not gonna lie I got jumpscared after reading the title and then looking at the code for the "simple human way". I think you may benefit from some refactoring. For example, why check if `a > b` and do the same thing twice in the `if` and the `else` block? Refactor that into a function.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yeah sounds like something AI would ask right?? xD

Comment: @Sourav At least this if statement  if (k == size2)
                ptr3[k - 1] = ptr[size - k] + carry; does not make sense because k is never equal to size2 due to its initialization for (int k = size2 + 1; k <= size; ++k) {

Comment: When the numbers have different sizes you start filling `ptr3` from left to right (and lose carries), when it's the same amount of digits you're doing ok -- you just need to print from index `0` upwards. I copied your code to https://ideone.com/2kb5eY and am messing with it a little bit (mainly formatting to my liking)

Comment: @Sourav In any case it is a bad code because indices in C start from 0. So indices in the for loops also should start from 0.

Comment: The "simple human way" starts at the least significant digits and works towards the left. If you work towards the right you mess up the carries!

Comment: Completely apart from the code and everything, I'm a little bit amazed to see a question tagged "turbo-c" in 2023. Didn't the last version of that come out in the 90s?

Comment: TurboC is obsolete and not standard compliant. Consider installing a Linux distribution (e.g. [Debian](https://debian.org/)...) and use [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: @Wintermute because Indian schools have not updated their courseware or sylybus in 30 years perhaps.  Easier to keep churning the same material year after year than actually maintaining the currency of a course.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch. Switching to Linux to get modern C compilation is somewhat drastic - two new things to learn.  MinGW GCC or MSVC (via Visual Studio Community Edition) would be an easier transition.  The latter has the benefit of a far better (or at least easier to use) debugger than GDB.

Comment: Your question lacks examples of input that cause it to go wrong and the consequent output.  I doubt anyone is going to wade through that without a starting point.  Moreover, even the antique Turbo-C has a source level debugger - that would be a far more productive debug method than posting questions here.  Most contributors would probably rather disregard your code and offer a better solution than to try and fix your approach - it would be simpler.

Comment: Terrible variable naming BTW.  `ptr` tells me it is a pointer perhaps, but that is already known by the declaration.  It would be far better to name it for what it points to.  In this case perhaps `operand1`.  I would also suggest that if you have xxx2, you should have a corresponding xxx1 not just xxx.

Comment: addition simple human way: https://ideone.com/mOORkv

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- when you detect a memory allocation failure, you should exit the program to avoid undefined behavior when you access the arrays which allocation failed.
- reading the digits as separate numbers is cumbersome: you should use `scanf("%1d", &ptr[i])` to read single digits even as they are typed consecutively.
- you do not check for allocation failure of the result array.
- initializing the array pointed to by `ptr3` is useless as `calloc()` already set all bytes to `0`, which guarantees that all elements accessed as `int` are `0`.
- in the first 2 addition loops, you should store the summed digit in the entry at `ptr3[size3 - k]`.
- the second loop in theses cases is incorrect: you should write

  ```
    for (int k = size2 + 1; k <= size; ++k) {
        ptr3[size3 - k] = ptr[size - k] + carry;
        carry = ptr3[size3 - k] / 10;
        ptr3[size - k] = ptr3[size - k] % 10;
    }
  ```

  or using `carry` to store the intermediary result:

  ```
    for (int k = size2 + 1; k <= size; ++k) {
        carry = carry + ptr[size - k];
        ptr3[size - k] = carry % 10;
        carry = carry / 10;
    }
  ```
- you should store the most significant digit as `ptr3[0] = carry`;
- in the case where `size == size2`, you use a different approach with a downward loop, but the boundaries are incorrect and you access an element beyond the end of the arrays at the first iteration. Furthermore you should store the digits in the result array at the next index to make space for the possible non zero leading digit:

  ```
     for (int k = size; --k > 0;) {
        ptr3[k + 1] = carry + ptr[k] + ptr2[k];
        carry = ptr3[k + 1] / 10;
        ptr3[k + 1] = ptr3[k + 1] % 10;
     }
     ptr3[0] = carry;
  ```

  or using `carry` to store the intermediary result:

  ```
     for (int k = size; --k > 0;) {
        carry = carry + ptr[k] + ptr2[k];
        ptr3[k + 1] = carry % 10;
        carry = carry / 10;
     }
     ptr3[0] = carry;
  ```
- note however that there is no need for a third case, the case where `size == size2` can be handled by the first or second case or a combined approach, adding the digits on the smaller of both lengths and propagating the carry through the remaining digits.
- in the last loop, you output only digits of the result that are non zero: this is incorrect, you should only skip the leading zeroes.

Here is a modified version with a combined approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3;
    int size1, size2, size3, minsize, carry;
    
    printf("Enter size of 1st number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &size1) != 1 || size1 <= 0)
       return 1;
    ptr1 = (int *)calloc(size1, sizeof(int));
    if (ptr1 == NULL) {
        printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < size1; ++j) {
        if (scanf("%1d", &ptr1[j]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }

    printf("\nEnter size of 2nd number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &size2) != 1 || size2 <= 0)
        return 1;
    ptr2 = (int *)calloc(size2, sizeof(int));
    if (ptr2 == NULL) {
        printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < size2; ++j) {
        if (scanf("%1d", &ptr2[j]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Addition starts here

    if (size1 > size2) {
        minsize = size2;
        size3 = size1 + 1;
    } else {
        minsize = size1;
        size3 = size2 + 1;
    }
    ptr3 = (int *)calloc(size3, sizeof(int));
    if (ptr3 == NULL) {
        printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // handle digits up to the smaller number size
    carry = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < minsize; ++k) {
        carry = carry + ptr1[size1 - k - 1] + ptr2[size2 - k - 1];
        ptr3[size3 - k - 1] = carry % 10;
        carry = carry / 10;
    }
    // handle remaining digits of the first number if it is larger
    for (int k = minsize; k < size1; ++k) {
        carry = carry + ptr1[size1 - k - 1];
        ptr3[size3 - k - 1] = carry % 10;
        carry = carry / 10;
    }
    // handle remaining digits of the second number if it is larger
    for (int k = minsize; k < size2; ++k) {
        carry = carry + ptr2[size2 - k - 1];
        ptr3[size3 - k - 1] = carry % 10;
        carry = carry / 10;
    }
    // store the most significant digit of the result (0 or 1)
    ptr3[0] = carry;

    //  DISPLAY     
    for (int j = 0; j < size1; ++j) {
        printf("%d", ptr1[j]);
    }
    printf("+");
    for (int j = 0; j < size2; ++j) {
        printf("%d", ptr2[j]);
    }
    printf(" = ");
    for (int j = (ptr3[0] == 0); j < size3; ++j) {
        printf("%d", ptr3[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

You may also want to read this question: [Calculating a very large integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188790/calculating-a-very-large-integer) and my answer which provides *additional* insight (pun intended).